# Pythonic way to check for membership and get member

Tags: python, any

```
a_set = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
word = 'foobar'
for item in a_set:
  if item in word:
    print(item)
```

I'd like for the below code to do what the above code does

```
if any(item in lst for item in word):
  # print(item)
```

I like this syntax more because it's easier to read. But is there a way to retrieve the item value that returned True in any()? Or is there another function for this?

Comment: In Python 3.8 there will be a walrus operator that does exactly that.

Comment: You are looking for the intersection of the two collections. Using `if any(...)` is asking an entirely different question, whose answer is not what you seek.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `set.intersection`, which also has the nice effect of O(1) membership testing* versus linearly O(N) scanning the string:

```
>>> a_set = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
>>> word = 'foobar'
>>> a_set.intersection(word)
{'a', 'b'}
```

<sup>*Specifically, calling `a_set.intersection(word)` will still require a once-over O(N) scan of `word` to convert it to a `set` internally.  However, each check from then on is O(1) (for each member of `a_set`).  You can contrast this to the snippet in your question, where each individual check is O(N).</sup>

---

The second part of your question is asking something slightly different, it seems; the equivalent of the `any()` call would be:

```
>>> if a_set.intersection(word):
...     # do something
```

where the condition will test `True` if the intersection contains 1 or more elements.

Comment: you need to scan the string once with `O(n)` though

Comment: You have O(1) membership testing for n members.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [85]: a_set = {'a', 'b', 'c'} 
    ...: word = 'foobar'                                                                                     
In [86]: [item for item in a_set if item in word]                                                            
Out[86]: ['b', 'a']
```

is the list comprehension equivalent of your first loop.

What are you trying to do with the second loop.  Seems you've switched the string and list.  The expression isn't any clearer to me.